# How can i stretch the div vertically as the text gets longer in html and css?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a food card but there is something wrong.I want the 'food-div-desc-div' stretches vertically as the 'food-div-desc' gets longer.

I tried to set the height to auto or fit-content but it didn't work.How can I solve this ?

```
    <div id="food-div-stack-div">

        <a style="text-decoration: none;" id="food-div-link" href="foodlinkcomeshere">

            <div id="food-div">

                <div id="food-div-photo-div"></div>


                <div id="food-div-header-div"><h1 id="food-div-header">Yaprak Sarma</h1></div>

                <div id="food-div-desc-div"><p id="food-div-desc">A delicious combination of  leaves,mince</p></div>
            </div>



        </a>


    </div>
```

Comment: paste your css code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the **food-div-desc-div** stretch vertically as the **food-div-desc** gets longer, you can use CSS flexbox or CSS grid.

```css
#food-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#food-div-desc-div {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="food-div-stack-div">

        <a style="text-decoration: none;" id="food-div-link" href="foodlinkcomeshere">

            <div id="food-div">

                <div id="food-div-photo-div"></div>


                <div id="food-div-header-div"><h1 id="food-div-header">Yaprak Sarma</h1></div>

                <div id="food-div-desc-div"><p id="food-div-desc">A delicious combination of  leaves,mince</p></div>
            </div>



        </a>


    </div>
```